# How to generate chart from result

Tags: sas

I am currently learning SAS programming and am having difficulty figuring out how to generate a pie chart from the results. Any direction someone with more experience can give me is much appreciated.

[image]

```
proc freq data=sashelp.cars;
where lowcase(type)^="hybrid";
table type*origin / nocum nopercent norow nocol;

proc gchart data=???;
```

============

***UPDATE***

============

I figured out thanks to the answer on this page what mistake I was making. I was putting two columns in for the pie chart, but not putting the second column into the option for detail.

```
proc freq data=sashelp.cars;
where lowcase(type)^="hybrid";
table type*origin / nocum nopercent norow nocol;

proc gchart data=sashelp.cars;
where lowcase(type)^="hybrid";
pie origin / detail=type;

run;
quit;
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Now you've got what you wanted, consider what an abominable visualisation the pie chart actually is - e.g.http://www.entrepreneur.com/article/239932

Comment: Lol! Yes. Good article too. I do avoid using pie charts, but in this case, I am merely working though all the different chart types while learning SAS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the official site](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/graphref/65389/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0rykxji060wvzn1x2crrwuhvfzy.htm)

```
title "Types of Vehicles Produced Worldwide (Details)";

proc gchart data=sashelp.cars;
pie type / detail=drivetrain
detail_percent=best
detail_value=none
detail_slice=best
detail_threshold=2
legend
;
run;
quit;
```

> This graph uses the data set entitled `CARS` found in the `SASHELP`
>   library. The `DETAIL=` option produces an inner pie overlay showing the
>   percentage that each `DRIVETRAIN` contributes toward each type of
>   vehicle. The `DETAIL_PERCENT=` option and the `DETAIL_SLICE=` option
>   control the positioning of the detail slice labels. The `DETAIL_VALUE=`
>   option turns off the display of the number of `DRIVETRAINS` for each
>   detail slice. The `DETAIL_THRESHOLD=` option shows all detail slices
>   that contribute more than 2% of the entire pie. The `LEGEND` option
>   displays a legend for the slice names and their midpoint values,
>   instead of printing them beside the slices.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding what you are asking. If so, let me know and I will fix or remove this answer

Comment: No, you pointed out to me exactly what I was missing. Answer accepted, and thank goodness for that. I don't want to lose anymore reputation points just because I asked a question about a syntax I have only used for two days.